# Run batch only on one server

Tags: spring, spring-boot, distributed

I have a Spring boot MVC and batch application. Both the batch and MVC share the DAO and Service layers so they are in the same war file. They are deployed into 4 cloud servers and there is a load balance and vip configured for the UI application. So the MVC application is fine.

The problem is as part of the batch i do FTP of a file to an external server and that external server FTPs the processed file back. The processed file comes back only to one among the 4 servers. So I want the batch to run only on 1 server. How do i suppress the batch from executing in the other servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution becomes easier as your 4 instances are running on 4 different cloud severs. The starting point of the batch can be a file poller. So if the file is dropped into the polled directory on server 1, the batch job on server 1 will be invoked. The other instances do nothing as there is no file dropped on that server.

You need to integrate file poller before spring batch. Something like this - http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/springBatchIntegration.html

```
<int:channel id="inboundFileChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outboundJobRequestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>

<int-file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filePoller"
channel="inboundFileChannel"
directory="file:/tmp/myfiles/"
filename-pattern="*.csv">
<int:poller fixed-rate="1000"/>
</int-file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:transformer input-channel="inboundFileChannel"
output-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel">.    <bean class="io.spring.sbi.FileMessageToJobRequest">
<property name="job" ref="personJob"/>
<property name="fileParameterName" value="input.file.name"/>
 </bean>
</int:transformer>

<batch-int:job-launching-gateway request-channel="outboundJobRequestChannel"
reply-channel="jobLaunchReplyChannel"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of many approaches but a way to achieve is keep a value in property file and set it's value to Boolean true

Now handle your batch to run only if property file value is true.

This way it gives you flexibility to change the server you want to handle batch job.